# Ember: How to assign a click handler on a parent element on handling a click

Tags: ember.js, click, event-bubbling

In my view, I have an action tied to an element. This action changes a property, and I have a method on the view that observes the property and acts on its changes. This method then assigns a click handler to the `window`. The problem I'm having is that the click handler on `window` is being fired by the initial action's click.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

```
// hbs file
<span class="icon-account" {{action 'showMenu' target="view"}}></span>

// view file
menuShowing: false,

menuShowingHandlers: function() {
  var MENU_CLICK = 'click.AccountMenu';

  if (this.get('menuShowing')) {
    // Close menu if anywhere in window is clicked
    $(window).on(MENU_CLICK, _.bind(function(){
      this.set('menuShowing', false);
    }, this));
    // Don't close menu if menu is clicked
    this.$().on(MENU_CLICK, function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
  } else {
    // Remove listeners
    $(window).off(MENU_CLICK);
    this.$().off(MENU_CLICK);
  }
}.observes('menuShowing'),

actions: {
  showMenu: function () {
    this.set('menuShowing', true);
  }
}
```

Initially, `showMenu` is called, setting the property to `true`. `menuShowingHandlers` is then called, at which point, the handler is assigned to `window`. However, immediately, the handler on `window` is called, thus resetting `menuShowing` back to false.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I'm not sure why code would help answer this question. I know what the problem is: I click, assign a handler, and that handler immediately is bubbled the initial click. I'm obviously using ember wrong in some way.

Comment: Have fun solving your identified problem.

Comment: There @LajosArpad , now that I've wasted my time, please bestow me with your brilliance.

Comment: Try wrapping the contents of `menuShowingHandlers` in an `Ember.run`. Deferring to the next run cycle may solve your issue.